# Como eliminar "Undefined"

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, undefined, google-adsense

Tengo un sitio web con Frontity (basado en React), coloqué un bloque de anuncios de Adsense en la mitad de un post y todo funcionaba bien, sin embargo, en los dispositivos con AdBlock, se bloquea el paquete de los anuncios y  aparece el error en la consola ("adsbygoogle is not defined"), entonces se detiene la ejecución o carga del sitio web y aparece la pantalla en blanco.

Me explico, Frontity funciona con React, pero la "base de datos" se toma del listado de post de WordPress. El bloque con el script lo coloqué en medio de un post en WordPress. Los anuncios Si cargan y todo el sitio funciona bien. Pero en los navegadores con AdBlock, aparece que la clase "adsbygoogle" no está definida y corta el proceso de carga de la web y aparece la pantalla en blanco.

Los errores que me aparecen son:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El script que coloqué fue el siguiente:

```
<div align="center"
  style="min-width: 200px; max-widht:100%; overflow: hidden;">
  <script async=""
    src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXX"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Display Horizontal -->
  <ins class="adsbygoogle"
    style="display:block"
    data-ad-client="XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    data-ad-format="auto"
    data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
  <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  </script>
</div>
```

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de solucionar este problema, es decir, que aunque el navegador tenga AdBlock no se corte o termine el proceso de carga de la Web (obviamente sé que no aparecerán anuncios).

He intentado utilizar algunas condicionales que sugieren en internet peo no me han funcionado:

```
<div align="center"
  style="min-width: 200px; max-widht:100%; overflow: hidden;">
  <script async=""
src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXX"
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Display Horizontal -->
  <script>
    if(adsbygoogle =! undefined){
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
      style="display:block"
      data-ad-client="XXXXXXXXXXXX"
      data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXXXXX"
      data-ad-format="auto"
      data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
    } else {
      null
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  </script>
</div>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: Sólo apuntar que: `adsbygoogle =! undefined` está mal escrito, el signo `!` va delante de `=` y no detrás: `adsbygoogle != undefined`. Por otro lado, `undefined` es una [variable `falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), podrías hacer directamente: `if(!adsbygoogle)`. Saludos

Comment: Gracias, ya entiendo. Ahora ¿cómo puedo parar la ejecución o saltar la linea de código del script de Adsense, en el caso de que la variable sea "undefined"?

Comment: proba poniendo la clase o id ad/ads/advert/advertising/banner/banners al div contenedor, testear si `window.adsbygoogle` es undefined cuando la carga es async pierde sentido debido a cómo se rellenan los "slots" `(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})` significa que si no existe `adsbygoogle` crear un array con ese nombre y pushear un elemento, cuando el script termina su carga async se crea una clase que toma ese array y suplanta el metodo `push` ver AB test https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=es